# How to ensure a provided numeric value is a positive integer in python

Tags: python

Sometimes upon receiving numeric parameters it is required to check whether the received numeric value is or not is a positive integer value.

How can we do this in python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way:

```
if isinstance(number, int) and number > 0:
    # number is a positive integer
```